# Why is my Selenium JUnit test bypassing @Before & @After annotations?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have written some code to print out the words "Setting up " and then run the test and then print out "Closing the test". But Selenium is skipping my [Before] and [After] methods and only running the test by itself.

```
package smoketests;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class PageTitleJUnit {

    @Test
    public void PageTitleTest() {
        System.out.println("Running the test");
        String webURL = "http://sdettraining.com/trguitransactions/AccountManagement.aspx";

        WebDriver driver = utilities.DriverFactory.open("Chrome");
        driver.get(webURL);
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        String expectedTitle = "SDET Training | Account Management";

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle, actualTitle);            
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Setting up");   
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Closing the test");
    }

}
```

For some reason it's only printing out "Running the test" from the @Test Method and it's skipping my Before and After methods. I tried re-writing the code, and restarting eclipse. But nothing's helped so far. Here's a screenshot of the console log.[image: Eclipse Console Screenshot]

Comment: `Selenium is skipping my [Before] and [After] methods and only running the test by itself.` What do you mean by this? You are running as JUnit test right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. "Before" means it should run the code block before the "Test" is run. And "After" means it should run that line of code after the test is done. But it's skipping both "before" and "after".  - https://imgur.com/a/w5mXX

Comment: what junit version?

Comment: How do I find out which Junit version I am using currently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is you have mixed up both the [**`JUnit 4.x`**](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-1-basic-usage/) annotations and [**`JUnit 5.x`**](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) annotations.

The basic annotations of **`JUnit 4.x`** are as follows :

- **`@BeforeClass`**
- **`@AfterClass`**
- **`@Before`**
- **`@After`**
- **`@Test`**

You have resolved **`@Before`** and **`@After`** annotations respectively through **`import org.junit.Before;`** and **`import org.junit.After;`**

But you have referenced **`@Test`** through **`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`**

### Solution

- Remove the references of **`JUnit 5.x`** external jars from your `Project Workspace`.
- Resolve **`@Test`** annotation through **`import org.junit.Test`**.
- `Clean` the `Project Workspace` through your `IDE`.
- `Execute` your **`Tests`**.

Comment: I just did. I was just wondering, how does up-voting help with your account ?

Comment: @Bekind This will explain the system and how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation